# jquery ajax show function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have been using this function to load data from a php file:

```
$('#form form').submit(function(){
    $('#content').empty();
    $.get('data.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){                          
        $('#content').html(data);               
    });         
    return false;
});
```

What I want is to show data with some animation like the `fadeIn` effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just with:

```
$('#form form').submit(function(){
$('#content').empty();
$('#content').fadeOut();
$.get('data.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){                          
$('#content').html(data);   
$('#content').fadeIn();            
});         
return false;
});
```

Comment: My bad, didn't notice you added a `.fadeOut` before the `$.get`. Some proper indenting doesn't hurt, and please re-use your selectors. Those jQuery methods return the jQuery object itself, you can chain the methods without having to use a new selector for every action.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the suggested edits to htynkn's answer, you can do this:

```
$('#form form').submit(function(){
    var $content = $('#content');
    $content.empty().fadeOut();
    $.get('data.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){                          
        $content.html(data).fadeIn();            
    });         
    return false;
});
```

You get minification and efficiency benefits from declaring the local variable `$content` plus you can chain as was suggested. You could also just use `.hide()` instead of `.fadeOut()`.